# Pandas: converting yyyy-mm-dd to dd Mon yyyy

Tags: python, pandas, date

I am having date field like(reading from a csv file) :

```
Date:
28 Apr 2020
29 Apr 2020
12 Mar 2020
11 Mar 2020
9 Mar 2020
```

was trying to sort the value by date like:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['Date'])
```

But it was not working. So I converted it to pandas datetime format like:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

and then sort the column like:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['Date'])
```

the sort is working fine, but I would like to covert the Date column back to the original format

Comment: Use `df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%d %b %Y')`